# Alphanumeric full text search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

```
PUT employee
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "tokenizer" : {
                    "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                        "type" : "edgeNGram",
                        "min_gram" : "2",
                        "max_gram" : "10",
                        "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]                            
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "data_Analyzer": {
                        "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                        ],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "mappings": {
                "employee": {
                    "properties": {
                        "groupId": {
                            "type": "long",
                            "index": "no"
                        }
                        "displayId": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "data_Analyzer"
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have a data in below combination

1)groupId:1, displayId: E0SZ5D8
2)groupId:1, displayId: E0FS4ED
3)groupId:1, displayId: 1234567
4)groupId:1, displayId: EJKDSHS
5)groupId:2, displayId: .....
6)groupId:2, displayId: .....

with the below elastic query :

```
GET /employee/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "groupId": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "displayId": {
              "query": "E0SZ5D8",
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    } 
  }
}
```

Its returning the data matching **E0SZ5D8, E0FS4ED**

When we see **explain : true**.

Its peels the search text token as : E0, E0S, S, 5, D8, 8 ... but not an whole string "E0SZ5D8"

As i am looking for an exact match(type: boolean) it should not return all but should with only a results matching "E0SZ5D8"

Comment: Then use `term` instead of `match`. And as input term, lowercase the text.

Comment: Also, I doubt that's your real mapping. If `groupId` is configured as `"index": "no"` then you wouldn't be able to do `"term": {
            "groupId": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }` as there is no term in the inverted index.

Comment: Anyway, instead of the `match` query you should be doing this: `"term": {
            "displayId": {
              "value": "e0sz5d8"
            }
          }`